# What is the meaning of OIFS=$IFS; IFS="|"; in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to understand a test script, which includes the following segment:

```
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS="|";
```

Comment: `IFS` is the internal field separator; see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash) with its accepted answer. `OIFS` just stores the `O`ld value, so it's easy to reset it.

Answer (score 8):

OIFS here is a user defined variable that serves to backup the current Bash [internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) value.

Then the internal field seperator variable is set to a user defined value, likely to enable some sort of parsing / text processing algorithm that relies on it and to be restored to its original value somewhere later in the script.

Answer (score 3):

IFS is internal field separator. The snippet is changing the IFS to "|" after saving old value so the it can be restored later.

Example:

```
->array=(one two three)
->echo "${array[*]}"
one two three
->IFS='|'
->echo "${array[*]}"
one|two|three
```

Answer (score 0):

In shell whenever we need to access the value of a variable, we use `$variableName` and whenever we need to assign some value to a variable we use `variableName=xxx`.
Therefore:-

```
# here we assigning the value of $IFS(Internal Field Separator) in OIFS.
OIFS=$IFS;
# and here we are re-assigning some different value to IFS.
# it's more like, first we store old value of IFS variable and then assign new value to it. So that later we can use the old value if needed.
IFS="|";
```